# badge/notification count not updating when application is background

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

In current application, locally checking whether application has new messages or not. If application is in background and there are 5 messsages arrived I need to display badge count on application icon as 5 only and still application should be there in background.

How can I achieve this using ionic?

Answer (score 0):

It's long to implement and I don't know where you are stuck, but, in short, you have to consider three aspects :

1. Configure the server to push the notifications (with a messaging solution such as [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/))
2. Receive the push notifications in the app (with an [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/) or Cordova plugin)
3. Instead of displaying a notification, change the badge on the app icon (with an [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/badge) or Cordova plugin)

Comment: Thank you @XavierBrt. Currently checking in application only there is any new message appear and it is inviewed displaying count for those messages only. so say for an example application is in background and new message added through webservice where checking in application through provider only whether it is new and unviewed update count and display badge count in background only

Comment: Installed https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/background-mode/ and after that getting such error as plugin not installed.  this.backgroundMode.isActive();